# Use curl to download an LDAP attribute value only

Tags: curl, ldap

I am using the following curl command to download a value from an LDAP directory:

```
curl  ldap://example.com/CN=ACME-Test-CRL,O=ACME?certificateRevocationList;binary -o crl.crl
```

The problem is it writes the following to the file crl.crl:

```
DN: CN=ACME-Test-CRL,O=ACME certificateRevocationList;binary: MIICxzCBsAIBATAN...
```

When I only want the base64 encoded CRL i.e., that starting MIICxzCBsAIBATAN

Is there anyway to tell curl to just write the base64 encoded binary value to the file?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue when trying to apply the CRL of my Active Directory CA on OpenVPN's "crl-verify" command.

My solution is the following:

```
curl -o CAName.ldap -u domain\\username:password "ldap://domaincontroller.domain.local/CN=CAName,CN=ServerName,CN=CDP,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=local?certificateRevocationList" && grep -Po '(?<=certificateRevocationList:: )(.+)' CAName.ldap > CAName.b64 && base64 -d CAName.b64 > CAName.der && openssl crl -inform DER -in CAName.der -outform PEM -out CAName.pem
```

Explanation:

```
curl -o CAName.ldap -u domain\\username:password "ldap://domaincontroller.domain.local/CN=CAName,CN=ServerName,CN=CDP,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=local?certificateRevocationList"
```

This command downloads the binary part with the DN and the base64 encrypted content to the output file "-o CAName.ldap". The "-u" part is needed for non anonymous ldap binding.

```
grep -Po '(?<=certificateRevocationList:: )(.+)' CAName.ldap > CAName.b64
```

This gets the base64 part into the new file "CAName.b64"

```
base64 -d CAName.b64 > CAName.der
```

Decrypt base64 content (into binary from ldap query) into new file "CAName.der"

```
openssl crl -inform DER -in CAName.der -outform PEM -out CAName.pem
```

Now convert DER (binary) into PEM for OpenVPN's "crl-verify".

You can verify the content with openssl:

```
openssl crl -inform PEM -text -noout -in CAName.pem
```

Answer (score 2):

**4 year later...**

The file that you are receiving is in [The LDAP Data Interchange Format (LDIF)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2849) format. So best case, you would use an `LDIF` parse to fetch `certificateRevocationList` attribute (see bellow). **However**, none of CRL servers that I have came across properly apply the LDIF syntax so parsers have difficulties understanding these files. This leaves you with manual parsing:

```bsh
curl ldap://endpoint | 
  sed -n 's/[[:space:]]*certificaterevocationlist;binary:: \(.*\)/\1/p' > file.crl
```

The code above saves the base64 formatted value of CRL into `file.crl`. You can, however, directly pipe the code into `openssl` for further processing:

```bsh
curl ldap://endpoint | 
  sed -n 's/[[:space:]]*certificaterevocationlist;binary:: \(.*\)/\1/p' |
  base64 --decode |
  openssl crl -inform der -noout -text
```

**A word of advise:**

It should be noted that *parsing* structured data manually, i.e. using `grep`, `awk`, etc., is generally a very **bad** idea. I use `sed` here as the last resort as none of the parsers that I tried out ([`Net::LDAP::Entry`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl-ldap/lib/Net/LDAP/Entry.pod) for Perl, [`ldif`](https://pypi.org/project/ldif/) for Python, and [`ldif`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ldif) for nodeJS) were able to parse the LDIF file without any prior modifications.